# Parse a math formula in an HTML form input and output the results to the same field

Tags: javascript, html, forms

What I'm wanting to do is have an input box which can either accept direct input of a dollar figure ($10.99) or also have the ability for the user to enter a calculation-- such as the user entering "2x9.99" or "2*9.99" or "9.99 + 9.99" etc... and after they type that, the value is outputted back to that same input field as the result, such as 19.98 in the example.

I've done some searching, but cannot figure out exactly how to accurately ask the question to find a good answer. And hour of searching and I'm no closer. I'm a PHP/MYSQL developer, and I figured this is a JS job, which I'm just a small hack at.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use an existing library, google can help, found hundreds in one search.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service

Comment: google it as "calculator  javascript"

Comment: consider using a controlled component with a managed state

Comment: You can choose to support ECMAScript syntax for mathematic expressions and just *eval* the  value, or you can create your own syntax, parse the value and evaluate it yourself. What have you chosen? If using *eval*, you may want to parse it first to check that it only contains suitable characters (e.g. 0-9, +, -, /, *, ., etc.)

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
SO is a platform where you can get a good suggestion regarding your problems.  But for that, you need to be more specific about what you are asking?  what have you done so far?  Before asking please see the suggested SO question and take a look at them. Still, you did not find a solution then you can ask a question here.

Answer (score 3):

Working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/mtmopq37/1/

Your HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="foo" value='enter math' onblur="matthy(this)">
```

Your Javascript:

```
function matthy(obj) {
obj.value = eval(obj.value);
}
```

Obviously this requires some serious validation.

Using PHP you can use `eval()` to evaluate a string (from your input field) and output the result. This requires some Javascript AJAX if you don't want a page refresh.

```
<?php

$input = $_POST['myinputfield'];
eval('$result = '.$input.';');

print($result);
?>
```

Comment: There should be some validation of the input value, especially if it's going to be evaluated at the server.

Comment: @RobG Absolutely, by no means the above is complete code.

Answer (score 1):

Depends if you want to handle multiple invalid entries, then there are lots of js library in the net. (i.e. [calculator-parser](http://jorendorff.github.io/calc/docs/calculator-parser.html)

If not you can do it the quick way in javascript

```
let value = $("input").value;

// replace x with asterisk and replace dollar with blank
eval(value.replace(/[xX]/g, "*").replace(/\$/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

it is easy first create an input and button and result then create function calculate in the script tag to calculate the input

```
 <input id="calc"  />
 <button onclick="calculate()">calculate</button>
 <div id="result"></div>
<script>
function calculate(){
    document.getElementById('result')
  .innerText=eval(document.getElementById('calc').value);
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like doing these things on the server side ( lol ) and I been working with PHP based lexer parser type stuff lately so I thought I would share this. **splat**

```
$names = ['num', 'op', 'paren']; //'whitespace','unknown'  I'm tossing these commented out ones, you could keep them I suppose if you wanted.
$pattern = '/(?P<num>[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)|(?P<op>x|\*|\+|-|\/|^)|(?P<paren>\(|\))|(?P<whitespace>[\r\n\t\s]+)|(?P<unknown>.+?)/';
$subject = "
    ($5.89 + 6.89) *
    ($7.89 + 9)
";

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

echo '<pre>';

$count = count( $matches[1] );

$tokens = [];

for( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ){
    foreach ( $names as $name ){
        if( isset( $matches[$name][$i] ) && $matches[$name][$i][1] != -1 ){
            $tokens[] = [
                    'type' => $name,
                    'value' => $matches[$name][$i][0]
            ];
            break;
        }
    }

}


var_export( $tokens );
```

And the output

```
array (
        0 =>
        array (
                'type' => 'paren',
                'value' => '(',
        ),
        1 =>
        array (
                'type' => 'num',
                'value' => '5.89',
        ),
        2 =>
        array (
                'type' => 'op',
                'value' => '+',
        ),
        3 =>
        array (
                'type' => 'num',
                'value' => '6.89',
        ),
        4 =>
        array (
                'type' => 'paren',
                'value' => ')',
        ),
        5 =>
        array (
                'type' => 'op',
                'value' => '*',
        ),
        6 =>
        array (
                'type' => 'paren',
                'value' => '(',
        ),
        7 =>
        array (
                'type' => 'num',
                'value' => '7.89',
        ),
        8 =>
        array (
                'type' => 'op',
                'value' => '+',
        ),
        9 =>
        array (
                'type' => 'num',
                'value' => '9',
        ),
        10 =>
        array (
                'type' => 'paren',
                'value' => ')',
        )
```

Then you just create a parser for the token stream above, with some rules on order of operation or what have you and, bingo!  Toss in a bit of Ajax and bango!